# git rebase drop commit does not restore my file

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have a problem after git rebase.
I did git commit, commit contains delete a file. So after that I did git pull and git has history of commits:

```
... -> My Commit -> Some Git commits came from remote->Recursive merge.
```

So my commit is in the middle. What I did:

```
git rebase -i <sha1 of a commit before my commit>
```

and removed the line that contains my commit.

I was expecting deleted file will be restored, since i dropped the commit that contains delete file, But It did not happen.

So I did not get my deleted files after rebase/drop commit. 
Is it something that is supposed to work like that or I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
git reset HEAD~1
```

and see if your file will pop up.
try it several times.

This will "drop" the current commit and the prevoius one will be the current one.